# How to set the dragging state properly when user drags out of the dragging zone using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to be able to drag and drop file into the DropZone div. when user drags in or drags out of the DropZone div i want the background color of the DropZone div to be grey.

Below is my code,

```
function MainComponent () {
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <SomeOtheComponent/>
        <DragAndDrop>
            <ListContent> //this is the children for the DragAndDrop component and want this to 
                //render within DragAndDrop component
                {condition_true && (
                    <FirstList/>
                )}
                {condition_true && (
                    <SecondList/>
                )}
            </ListContent>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}


const DragAndDrop: React.FC = ({ children }) => { //here i am passing children
    const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
    const [dragCounter, setDragCounter] = useState(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // componentDidMount()
        setDragCounter(0);
    }, []);

    const handleDrag = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    };

    const handleDragIn = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setDragCounter((prev: number) => prev + 1);
        if (e.dataTransfer.files) {
            setDragging(true);
        }

    };

    const handleDragOut = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setDragCounter((prev: number) => prev - 1);
        if (dragCounter === 0) {
            setDragging(false);
        }
    }; 

    const handleDrop = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setDragging(false);
        if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
            e.dataTransfer.clearData();
            setDragCounter(0);
        }
    }; 

    return (
        <DropZone //this is a styled component div and dropzone area where user can drop files
            onDragEnter={handleDragIn}
            dragging={dragging}
            onDragLeave={handleDragOut}
            onDragOver={handleDrag}
            onDrop={handleDrop}
        >
    );
};
```

Now this works fine however, when user drags file onto dropzone div dragging state is true and now if user drags file out of dropzone div (which is handleDragOut) the dragging state is still true.

It should be false...also i am not sure if i am setting dragcounter value correct or is needed.

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `handleDragOut` handler checks if `dragCounter` is zero, but this state hasn't been updated yet.

Here's an updated version:

```js
    const handleDragOut = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setDragCounter((prev: number) => prev - 1);

        if (dragCounter > 1) return;
        setDragging(false);
    };
```

And `handleDrop` should reset the counter regardless:

```js
  const handleDrop = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      setDragging(false);
      setDragCounter(0);
      if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
          e.dataTransfer.clearData();
      }
  };
```

In my opinion, a cleaner solution would be to use `useRef` for the counter. That way, counter updates won't cause unnecessary renders, and the counter is up-to-date right after it has been incremented/decremented.

Here's an example:

```js
const DragAndDrop = ({ onUpload, children }) => {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = React.useState(false);

  const dragCount = React.useRef(0);

  const handleDragIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    dragCount.current++;
    setIsDragging(true);
  };

  const handleDrag = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    setIsDragging(true);
  };

  const handleDragOut = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    dragCount.current--;
    if (dragCount.current > 0) return;
    setIsDragging(false);
  };

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    setIsDragging(false);
    dragCount.current = 0;
    const dt = e.dataTransfer;
    const files = dt.files; // FileList

    // Handle files ...
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundColor: isDragging ? 'red' : 'gray', padding: '20px'}}
      onDragEnter={handleDragIn}
      onDragOver={handleDrag}
      onDragLeave={handleDragOut}
      onDrop={handleDrop}
    >
      Drag here
      <div>A nested div</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In your case, instead of rendering a `div`, render the `DropZone` styled component like you did previously.

Comment: thanks the dragCounter value is 1 when in dragOut and hence dragging will not set to false based on your solution. is there something wrong with useEffect. there i set the dragCounter to 0. i am thinking if this updates dragCounter on componentdidupdate too.

Comment: Here's the code I posted: https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-n-drop-sample-5emqb It seems to work as intended. You decrement `setDragCounter` in `handleDragOut`, but since you use setState, the value hasn't been updated when the next line runs (`if (dragCounter > 1)`)

Comment: thanks it works almost correct. but as seen from code the maincomponent has Listcontent which has first and second list comoponents withing DragAndDrop component. when i drag the file onto the dropzone div and move it to these list items the dragging is set to false sometimes. how can i fix it.

Comment: Check my updated answer: I added another possibility, using `useRef` instead of `useState` for the counter. Could you try it out and see how it behaves together with your Listcontent?

Comment: so this dragCount ref in your solution should be used on the div where we drop files right??

Comment: You can use the component I posted as a replacement of your original `DragAndDrop` component (it's basically the same, just with `useRef` for the counter). Make sure you render your `DropZone` component (like you did originally), not the `div` in my example. I used a `div` to make it more generic.